# When working in visual studio we create Meta class why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

the code in model and meta class is the same so why we create why we just create a controller for the model it self

Comment: What meta class are you referring to? Keep in mind we're not in front of your computer, so we don't know what you've done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Meta data is usually used for validation purposes ... For more datail you can [visit here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation)